# adobe illustrator Scale tool

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator

In adobe illustrator,how we can use scale tool to scale an object so that it's sides move relatively.?
For example,if we push an anchor point inward,the opposite side will also move inward instead of moving outward?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGiFa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the object’s proportions as it scales, hold down Shift as you drag diagonally.

**Tip:** While using the Scale tool with the Shift key, start dragging at an angle of 45° horizontally or vertically but in an angle.

To scale the object along a single axis, hold down Shift as you drag vertically or horizontally.

[More tips can be found here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/scaling-shearing-distorting-objects.html).

**Update**

In reference to the video you mentioned.

First Draw your shape, in my case it was a square.

[image: Your Square]

Then create 2 new points using the pen tool by clicking at 2 opposite sides of the square (for this example i added mine to top and bottom, centered)

[image: First Point added]

[image: Second Point added]

Then using your direct select tool you click one anchor point then hold shift while selecting the other point. (Both Points show selected below)

[image]

Then change to your Scale tool and click and drag on screen to move your two points. (Click anywhere on screen and drag, you do NOT need to click on the points/handles.)

[image]

Comment: What i meant is that scaling the two sides of an object while the other two remain at their actual position(Say its a rectangle) and when we scale the one side outward while other selected,the other side would also go outward instead of going in the direction of the first side.

Comment: @dave Are you trying to make for example a square into a rectangle? So 2 sides get longer while 2 sides stay the same and the whole thing is still centered? Also are you using the latest version of illustrator?

Comment: No..i am trying to scale two anchor points without moving other anchor points.I just want to scale two anchor points relative to each.My concern here is that how we scale anchor points in different directions while keeping the distance between them constant.

Comment: Try watching this video and notice at 2:28:      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Y9unghEExw  >>Notice how  turns a square into another shape.I just want to know how he did it and how can i do this?

Comment: @daveritche i updated my answer with how to do what they showed in the video.

Comment: @daveritche please mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem, if not please let us know and we can continue to help. :)

Comment: It actually didn't help.Perhaps it is the version problem.I am using illustrator CS6 and in the video it was Illustrator CC..

Comment: @daveritche i used a friends copy of SC6 to test the process and it works exactly the same way, I am updating my answer to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much!This time the object scaled the way i wanted it to.

Comment: Glad I could help. Make sure to accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by holding Alt key for Windows.

Wish helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to achieve what you show in your image is using the MirroMe plugin from Astute Graphics:
[AstuteGraphics MirrorMe AI Plugin](https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/mirrorme)

In that case you will only create one half of the square, the other one will be created automatically and mirror exactly what you do, so when you move the anchor point inwards, the other one will do the same. Watch the demo video I linked for clarification.